# how do i update the database table on the basis of checkbox/unchecked

Tags: android, sqlite

[image: this is the xml layout of the checkboxes]

how can i retrieve the checkboxes value to update the database table on pressing the update button...

**TeacherLoggedInClass**

```
public class TeacherLoggedInPage extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button UpdateAttendanceButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.attendancesheet);

        UpdateAttendanceButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bUpdateAttendance);
        UpdateAttendanceButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The isChecked() method return a boolean value with the information you need.

I would also suggest you use another way with implementing the Listener. This is what Google recommends:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
 protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
     super.onCreate(icicle);

     setContentView(R.layout.content_layout_id);

     final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // Perform action on click... for example your checkBox.isChecked()
         }
     });
 }
```

Comment: how can i retrieve all the checkbox boolean values at a time to store it in database columns where each column uses each checkboxes respective values thanks in advance..

Comment: I do not know whether I got you right but I would just declare four boolean variables, read the checkbox1-4.isChecked() into those four variables and then update the database... is that what you asked? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the single checkbox value and set database, you can follow below code,

```
public class TeacherLoggedInPage extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button UpdateAttendanceButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.attendancesheet);

    UpdateAttendanceButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bUpdateAttendance);
    UpdateAttendanceButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (cbBox.isChecked()) {
        // do your operation
    } else {
        // do your operation
    }

}
```

}

if you need to use a list of checkbox status to update databases, you'd better to create a collection to cache every checkbox status , and with bulkInsert or transaction to commit.